# C# I have to find all possibe combinations between 4 numbers that are equal to their sum, problem with operator precedence

Tags: c#

For example, i have 4 numbers 9 17 3 15, with sum=44
The program must generate all the possible combinations and check which of them produces the desirable result.

What i've done so far is calculate all the possible combinations of the first two and save them in an array, then i use the wrapper functions in a loop
 funptrk;
but this breaks the operator precedance, cause it essentially does this:
(((9+17)*)3)-15 instead of this 9+(17*3)-15

But i don't know how to apply this with out breaking the operator precedence

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, because `9*17-3/15` is not equal to 44, it is `152.8`. Can you add more detail?

Comment: What does *breaking the operator precedence* really mean? Operator precedence works out of the box with C#

Comment: @knittl sorry i meant that the program must try all the operators between the numbers and check which sequence produces the desirable result, i will change it

Comment: Thanks, yes. That clears things up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `new DataTable().Compute()` you could transform your combinations/permutations into a string and compute the result - it will handle the operator precedence correctly for you.

Below is an example where I have skipped the part about finding all the permutations - you should have some fun yourself too :) Instead I've just made some sample permutations (`intPerms` and `opPerms`). The answer to your question lies in the `foreach` loops.

```
var ints = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var ops = new [] { "*", "/", "+", "-" };
var targetSum = ints.Sum();
Console.WriteLine("Integers: " + string.Join(",", ints));
Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + targetSum);

// Create all your permutations here...

// Permutations of 4 integers
var intPerms = new []
{
    new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    new [] { 1, 2, 4, 3 }
};

// Permutations of 4 operators
// 1 permutation only has 3 elements
var opPerms = new []
{
    new [] { "+", "*", "/" },
    new [] { "*", "*", "+" }
};

var matchingExpressions = new List<string>();

foreach (var intPerm in intPerms)
{
    foreach (var opPerm in opPerms)
    {
        var expression = intPerm
            // Zip merges the two arrays one element at a time
            // until one array runs out of elements
            .Zip(opPerm, (i, op) => $"{i}{op}")
            // Because intPerm has one more element we add it to the end
            .Concat(new [] { intPerm[intPerm.Length-1].ToString() })
            .Aggregate((init, next) => $"{init}{next}");

        // For example for intPerms[0] and opPerms[0]
        // expression will be "1+2*3/4"

        var result = new DataTable().Compute(expression, null);

        if (result is int && (int)result == targetSum)
        {
            matchingExpressions.Add(expression);
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Matching expressions:");
foreach (var expr in matchingExpressions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(expr);
}
```

Note that this example allows you to use longer combinations (as in: "more than just 4 numbers"). If you only need it for 4 numbers you could simplify the loops and get the `expression` to calculate like so:

```
var expression = $"{intPerm[0]}{opPerm[0]}{intPerm[1]}{opPerm[1]}{intPerm[2]}{opPerm[2]}{intPerm[3]}"
```